# Batch size does not affect speed in oracle insert

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Recently I've been working a lot with database inserts and selects.
Often working with multiple millions of data, I've realized that you need different approaches to these things. 
I've read up on batching a lot in oracle databases and it certainly provides a good performance boost but I'm not sure if it's working as intended in my case. So now I've managed to export about 2.8 million records very efficiently. (about 3.5 mins) I managed that with the fetch rows parameter.

Now it comes to importing that data back to the oracle database. I have a count of files. (1300 ~). I tried changing up the batch size and not seen any difference in performance. Am I using batch inserts correctly? 
I have tried :

1. Batch size 4: 7:07 min
2. Batch size 10: 6:02 min
3. Batch size 50: 8:42 min
4. Batch size 100: 8:56 min

I would have expected some kind of reasonable change but I don't think this makes a lot of sense.

```java
            Connection connection  = cpprov.getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            for (String fileName : fileNames) {

                // ... process data into array etc.. (datatypes, data, charSizes) 
                // ... create sql insert statement with 54 wildcard variables (sqlstatement)

                try (PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);){
                    for (int i = 1; i < lineCount; i++) {

                        String[] currentLineData = handleFieldInput(i, datatypes, data);
                        // insert parameters to the prepStatement 
                        handlePrepStatement(prepStatement, datatypes, currentLineData, charSizes);

                        prepStatement.addBatch();

                        if(i % batchSize == 0) {
                            int[] executedBatches;
                            try {
                                executedBatches = prepStatement.executeBatch();
                                connection.commit();
                                importedRecords += executedBatches.length;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LOG.error(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
                            } 
                        }
                    }

                    // execute remaining batches
                    int [] executedBatches = prepStatement.executeBatch();
                    importedRecords += executedBatches.length;
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

            cpprov.closeConnection(connection);
```

Obviously 7 minutes for insertion of 2.8 million records doesn't sound bad, but it does seem like there is some issue.

Comment: Batch execution saves you a little bit of overhead on network roundtrips and statement compilation, the latter is trivially small for simple insert statements. Clearly, with batches as small as 100 this overhead is negligible. Try larger batches.

Comment: I executed 1000 batch size, it resulted in 11 minutes runtime. 2000 is going to be around 10 ~ minutes. Since I have a locally running XE Database, it depends on my current workstation load, so it might vary a lot, but it seems to not have an impact at all.

Comment: If your database is running on the same system as the application, the effects of batching are negligible, and in fact batches might then be slower just because of the additional garbage collection overhead it might cause. Batches primarily shine when executing across a network link with higher latency or low throughput.

Comment: `String fileName`, so the data is in a file and has to be inserted into a database table? Is the table empty?

Comment: My java aint great, but I thought you had also explicitly nominate the batch size, ie, prepStatement.setExecuteBatch(nnn)

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald There is no such method in the JDBC API. If such a method exists, it would be a driver specific extension.